# Merging two post type in a single WP Query

Tags: wordpress

I want to fetch the data from two different post type within a single query having different arguments for both the post type.I am using following code but how can I combine two results in a single query?

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page'=> '1',
    );
    $args1 = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page'=> '3', 
    );
    $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $page_query = new WP_Query( $args1 );
```

Comment: You'll need two queries at least

Comment: Yes you can merge the `$posts` properties

Comment: Please check,I have updated my question.How can I combine two queries in a single query now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options, either merge the results or run a third query. I always like the latter because then you keep the query object in place which is quite helpful for post counters and pagination.

We need to be smart here as this can really slow things down unnecessary and can become quite expensive, so this is what we will do

- Run two very lean, very smart queries with `get_posts` (*more optimized as a normal `WP_Query` as it breaks pagination which makes it faster*). We will also just query the post ID's and not full objects. This will make these queries very fast and very lean. It will be almost like you never did those queries ;-)
- Once we have the results from those queries, we can merge the ID's and run a final query to return full post objects which we can use to run a proper loop

Lets look at the code

```
// Set our defaults to keep our code DRY
$defaults = [
    'fields'                 => 'ids',
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'cache_results'          => false
];
// Set query args for query 1
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
];
// Set query args for query 2
$args1 = [
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
];
$post_query = get_posts( array_merge( $defaults, $args  ) );
$page_query = get_posts( array_merge( $defaults, $args1 ) );

// Merge the two results
$post_ids = array_merge ( $post_query, $page_query ); //. You can swop around here

// We can now run our final query, but first mke sure that we have a valid array
if ( $post_ids ) {
    $final_args = [
        'post_type' => ['post', 'page'],
        'post__in'  => $post_ids,
        'orderby'   => 'post__in', // If you need to keep the order from $post_ids
        'order'     => 'ASC' // If you need to keep the order from $post_ids
    ];
    $loop = new WP_Query( $final_args );

    // Run your loop as normal
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use this example to query my posts. All working, but for some reason I cant loop through the results corretly. Could you post an example of what a loop would look like?

Comment: Nevermind, found that post_type needs to be set in the $final_args

Comment: 1 question; the cache parameters are being used in order to save time, since $defaults only needs the post IDS to be collected correct? This does not affect the cache results of $loop, whereas $loop does use the cache results correct?

Comment: Nice solution. It also allows for easy remove of duplicates before sending to final query....

Comment: Doesn't work. `Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string `